# Change the modified date of a file?

Tags: c#, file, uwp

In my Local folder I have a file `sample.txt`.

On rightclick -> properties -> Details

I can see its modified date. For example 30.10.2018 09:00.

Can I change this property trough UWP? To 20.10.2018 09:00 for example.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Tofik - why are you asking? How will you benefit from seeing what he has tried so far?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Some previous research might help us to narrow down the best solution, instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Because. If he even tried to look at google he would immidietly found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setlastwritetime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_SetLastWriteTime_System_String_System_DateTime_

This forum is not "My imps, do it for me".

Comment: @Tofik - so you're trying to educate? Rather than just addressing the question? This is not academia, it's a question and answer forum.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ This is about principle how this "forum" works.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ This is not a forum...

Comment: @Tofik - SO never used to be hung up on principles, it was about helping. This question lacks no clarity, I do believe you're wishing to see an attempt for the benefit of ensuring the OP has gone through necessary efforts himself before simply asking for the solution, which is ruining the website/forum/community/qandaformat. This is not college. If you have an answer, provide it.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Well you are completely wrong. We are here to help solve issues. He should put his effort to it. We shouldnt do his job for him. He should do some research first. Read something and then if he cant get it work, then create a question providing his solution and ask for help. This place is not for straight forward doing anybodys work for him, without trying himself.

Comment: @Tofik - you must feel a massive amount of self-importance if you're under the illusion that you're here to teach. As a contributor, you're here to offer technical solutions, not life guidance. Words like 'effort' and 'trying' are part of the movement that I firmly believe is crippling SO. He isn't at the mercy of how hard you think he has tried. Just answer the question!?

Comment: Of course, granted, this question could be worded a little better. But it was specific enough that Hamza managed to answer, so what's your problem?

Comment: The problem is that there is sufficient information on this site and elsewhere to answer this question without it having to be asked over and over again @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ

Comment: @PatrickHofman I haven't responded to you yet because you keep missing the point. That's not the problem at all, that's not the problem Tofik and I are discussing. Tofik is moderating the amount of effort and willingness that appears to be behind an attempt at solving a problem, as though he is a teacher in school. He feels that that is a justifiable approach, I feel it is what is changing SO (for the worse, in my opinion).

Comment: Yup, thats my point, approx. 3 minutes of effort and no more flooding about something, that has been already answered.

Comment: Why do you need to see effort? You're both missing the point entirely here. I'm not even disputing the fact OP is lazy, probably is - google brought back these results very simply. But we're not here to moderate that!?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ You just dont get it. Waste of time. Have a nice day, sorry we dont actually understand each other. It happens. Hope se your mood wasnt affected. Cya.

Comment: I'm out, the rest of this is just noise and this site is not designed for extended discussion. I don't expect you to understand if you haven't thus far. Conversation over.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Please see the first reason for a downvote: "This question doesn't show any research effort". This question clearly lacks any attempt.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question. My mistake was that I used File.SetLastWrite(x.Path,y) with x being StorageFolder x = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder; I then thought that it works differently on UWP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do it by the following way

```
string path = @"c:\sample.txt";

// Take an action that will affect the write time.
File.SetLastWriteTime(path, new DateTime(1985,4,3));
```

Comment: Good on you for simply answering the question and helping out.

Comment: yeah i would love to